# PDF preview in my jasper ireport not available

Tags: jasper-reports, netbeans-8, ireport, jasper-plugin

I am using jasper plugin in netbeans 8.2. I have designed a report but pdf preview option is not available.

[image: Jasper preview options]

[image: Options window of netbeans]